# How to delete Prometheus & Grafana data manually?

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus, grafana

I have a VM with `4GB` storage. I setup `Docker & Prometheus and Grafana` with the following config:

```
prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'    
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    expose:
      - 9090
    networks:
      - monitoring
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
     - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - monitoring
```

I forgot to add following flags to `Prometheus` entry.

```
 - "--storage.tsdb.retention.time=60m"
 - "--storage.tsdb.retention.size=512MB"
```

so my disk filled up pretty quickly and I cannot perform any operations due to disk space is full. I am getting errors like from different sources

```
error: file write error: No space left on device
```

```
logger=cleanup t=2022-12-11T14:06:53.402543926Z level=error msg="failed to lock and execute cleanup of old login attempts" error="database or disk is full"
```

```
ts=2022-12-11T13:38:35.765Z caller=db.go:908 level=error component=tsdb msg="compaction failed" err="compact head: persist head block: populate block: write chunks: preallocate: no space left on device"
```

I attempted to delete `prometheus` and `grafana` containers from `docker` but it did not help to reduce disk size.

How can I delete all the previously collected data (there I don't care about them) and start with those retention limitations?

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the docker volume:

docker volume ls # see what is the actual volume name
docker volume rm prometheus_data # or the actual volume name

after stoping and deleting the container.

Off course this means you will lose those data...